# What is #pragma region in c++ and VScode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I found out that we can hide code in VScode using `#pragma region` and `#pragma endregion`. I have two questions:

1. How does `#pragma region` work?
2. Will it affect compilation if I tried to compile the code on any other machine?

Comment: [`#pragma region`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/region-endregion) has no effect on compilation whatsoever. It is just a convenience tool for an IDE to expand/collapse snippets of code.

Comment: Any `#pragma` directive that is unknown to a compiler will be ignored. Some compilers may issue a warning.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The  `#pragma region` is specific to Visual Studio *only*.

Using `#pragma region` you can specify a block of code where you can expand it and collapse it.

It has *no* affect on compilation.

Here is an example:

```
// pragma_directives_region.cpp
#pragma region Region_1
void Test() {}
void Test2() {}
void Test3() {}
#pragma endregion Region_1

int main() {}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/region-endregion?view=vs-2019).

Like others have mentioned your compiler is allowed to silently ignore a `pragma`, Some will even give a warning depending on the specific compiler you are using. You need to read about your compiler's docs on `pragma`.

`gcc -Wall` also check for  unknown `pragma`s.

Comment: When you say ignore a `pragma`, are you referring to all `pragma`s?

Comment: I am referring to all the `pragma`s that may be *unknown* to the compiler, @DynamicSquid.

Comment: It should be noted that ignoring unknown pragmas (using -Wno-unknown-pragmas for example) should be approached cautiously, particularly if you have pragmas in your application code.

Answer (score 12):

First, `#pragma` is a C preprocessor **directive**. You're undoubtedly familiar with the `#include` and `#define` directives. Directives are used by the C preprocessor to perform certain actions before the code reaches the compiler.

The `#pragma` directive in particular is meant to pass implementation-specific information to whatever compiler you're using.

Here's what [GNU has to say](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html):

> The `#pragma` directive is the method specified by the C standard for providing additional information to the compiler, beyond what is conveyed in the language itself.

Here's what [Microsoft has to say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=msvc-160):

> Pragma directives specify machine-specific or operating system-specific compiler features.

Second, for Microsoft Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code, the `#pragma region` directive [defines a region of code that the compiler's UI can use for code-folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/region-endregion?view=msvc-160) (that is, hiding and showing blocks of code for readability). If a compiler cannot understand the `#pragma region` directive, then the directive is ignored.

Here's an example below:

1. Here's a chunk of C++ code in Visual Studio Code v1.60.0 (2021) on Mac. It would be great if I could hide and unhide the `private:` chunk of code. Note that when I mouse-over the UI, there is a down arrow chevron (⌄) to indicate foldable code for the comment block but not for the `private:` block.

[image]

2. Putting in a starting `#pragma region foo` and ending `#pragma endregion` will identify a block of code for code-folding. Notice that after the two `#pragma` directives are added, the code-foldable chevron symbol appears in the UI.

[image]

3. When you click on the chevron, the demarcated block will fold (hide). Clicking on the chevron again will unfold the block.

[image]